# Destruir activity y volver a abrirlo ejecutando todo otra vez

Tags: android-studio

Tengo el siguiente codigo que valida si hay conexion o no, tengo diferentes elementos que se muestran dependiendo el estado, si no hay conexion hago visible un boton que dice Volve a intentarlo, necesito q al dar click en ese boton, la app se reinicie y vuelva a ejecutar todo otra vez.
Probe con finish() y otros que lo hacen pero el ringProgress no se vuelve a ejecutar y queda el circulo sin hacer nada (reintentar_conexion.setOnClickListener)
Necesito que se destruya todo y vuelva a iniciar como si la hubiera abierto recien.

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


static RingProgressBar ringProgressBar;
static int progress = 0;
ImageView no_connect;
Button reintentar_conexion;

private static class MyHandler extends Handler {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == 0) {
            if (progress < 100) {
                progress++;
                ringProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        }
    }
}

private final MyHandler myHandler = new MyHandler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    ringProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_1);
    no_connect = findViewById(R.id.no_connect);
    reintentar_conexion = findViewById(R.id.reintentar_conexion);

    final Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    final Intent sa = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);

    no_connect.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    reintentar_conexion.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ringProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    ConnectivityManager con = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    assert con != null;
    final NetworkInfo networkInfo = Objects.requireNonNull(con).getActiveNetworkInfo();

    ringProgressBar.setOnProgressListener(new RingProgressBar.OnProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void progressToComplete() {

            if(networkInfo !=null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Verifica tu conexion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                no_connect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                reintentar_conexion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ringProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);



            }
        }
    });

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(40);
                    myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

    reintentar_conexion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            startActivity(sa);
        }
    });
}
```

}
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberias mejorar el codigo para q no necesites reiniciar la actividad

Pero si aun asi la quieres reiniciar aqui esta como:

```
   Intent intent = getIntent(); 
   finish();        
   startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Hola, sigue haciendo lo mismo, el ring queda sin ejecutarse. Ahi busco como mejorar el codigo, muchas gracias.

Comment: Es por onsavedinstancestate por ejemplo si pones el codigo en on resume y utilizas un boolean funcionaria, o utilizas otra actividad y destruyes la actividad actual y la reinicias

Comment: Lo mejor serias q llames un metodo

Answer (score 0):

Hola con este codigo te aseguras que se vuelva a ejecutar todo y limpia el stack de Activities que tengas abierto.

```
    Context mContext = this.getApplicationContext();
    Intent i = mContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage( mContext.getPackageName());
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    mContext.startActivity(i);
```

Ojala te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Cuando tenga la pc a mano me fijo muchas gracias, lo que si estoy viendo es que yo declaro esto: static int progress = 0; y voy haciendo un ++ hasta que llegue a 100 y ahi se ejecuta todo lo otro pero cuando vuelvo a llamar el activity ese dato debe seguir en 100 por eso no se ejecuta el ring ni todo lo otro, tal vez seteando en 0 ese dato funcione ok pero no me pude fijar todavia

Comment: te aconsejo que no andes guardando variables static de ese modo, siempre hay otras alternativas